# Setting second datepicker a year ahead of the first datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

On a project I'm working on, I'm using JQuery datepickers.  I've got two datepickers on one page, and I need my second datepicker to be initialized to be one year ahead of the first one (e.g. if `datepicker1` is set to 1/1/2019, I need `datepicker2` to be set to 1/1/2020).

I've got my current JavaScript below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(()=>{
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker();
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker("option", "dateFormat","dd-mm-yy");
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker();
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker("option", "dateFormat","dd-mm-yy");
    });
</script>
```

I'm not really familiar with the datepicker API.  How do I make my second datepicker initalize a year ahead of my first datepicker?

Comment: What datepicker library are you using? Update your question with that.

Comment: You have to hook into the select's *change* event to dynamically update the *maxDate* option of the other datepicker. ANd of course you need to verify the input in the processing script as well.

Comment: Revised question wording, code formatting, and title.  Removed unnecessary tags.  The initial wording was vague, 'ahead of' can mean a lot of things.  Please correct my correction if I interpreted wrong.  As to the tags, the question only uses JS6, and jQuery datepickers; there was no evidence of MySQL or PHP in the question.  Using tags relevant to the tech you're working on ensures that those of us best able to help, can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker();
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker();
    $('#datepicker1').on('change',function(){
       $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
      var minDate= $('#datepicker1').datepicker( "getDate" );
      minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 365); 
      console.log(minDate);
     $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(minDate) });   
      });
    });
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <body>
   <p>Date1: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
  <p>Date2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p> 
  </body>
</html>
```

You can do this by writing a change event to the datepicker1. For restricting date selection just set the minDate property to datepicker2. For checking 1-year gap here I added 365 days it may be wrong in some cases you can go for another logic.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks alot. Worked like charm.